# How to query which table field value is array

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent, subquery

Table 1

field = "accounts"
value = ["1","2","3"]

Table 2

field = "users"
value = ["2","3"]

```
Project::where('user_id', $uid)
            ->orWhere('user_id', 0)
            ->where(function($q)  {

                $table_2_data = ["2","3"];

                query here

            })
            ->orderBy('title', 'asc')
            ->get();
```

How could I query this in eloquent in where subquery.

Comment: not very clear what you're asking, but you may wanna try `whereIn`

Comment: I think you don't need a subquery for this.

Comment: @Saly3301The field value is array ["1", "2"] and the other field is array too, Now I want to compare if both ID exist both sides.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for `whereIn`, supply an array of IDs and Eloquent will look for any matching from the array

```php
Project::whereIn('user_id', [$uid, 0, 2, 3])
    ->orderBy('title', 'asc')
    ->get();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This doesn't work, the field value is already like this ["2","3"] array

Comment: Then change it to ["2", "3"] array